# Can set background image for UIBarButtonItem in nav bar, but not bottom toolbar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

So this works when adding the item to the nav bar, but when i add it to the toolbar set in the bottom bar via interface builder, the background image doesn't show up.

```
UIBarButtonItem *resetButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Reset" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(resetCriteria:)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
    img = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:20];
    [resetButtonItem setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

self.toolbarItems   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: resetButtonItem, nil];
```

Not only does the background not appear, none of the other behaviors work as well (but they work fine when adding these barbutton items to the nav bar)

Comment: The "via IB" comment is worrysome - you have code above but its added via IB? In anycase, if you could whip up a simple demo app, add two images, to show the problem - and put it on DropBox, would be glad to take a peek at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following method to do the same.

Setting custom view in UIBarButtonItem.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(resetCriteria:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *Item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.toolbarItems   = [NSArray arrayWithObject:Item];
[Item release];
```

We can set any view in UIBarButtonItem with CustomView init method.
We could set the ImageView. But ImageView doesnot handle UIControl Events.